# put icon at left of each button in spark ButtonBar flex 4

Tags: flex4, buttonbar

hello all i have the following:

```
<s:ButtonBar id="tabs" y="15" left="0" height="31"
             change="VideosMenuBar_changeHandler(event)" requireSelection="true">  
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout gap="1" columnWidth="180" variableColumnWidth="false"   
                            />
    </s:layout>

    <s:ArrayCollection>
        <fx:String>Latest Videos</fx:String>
        <fx:String>Last Week Videos</fx:String>
        <fx:String>Last Month Videos</fx:String>
    </s:ArrayCollection>

</s:ButtonBar>
```

can anyone tell me how can i embed an icon to the left of each button of this (spark)ButtonBar?? I have searched all the web!

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a skin class for the `ButtonBar` (e.g. `CustomButtonBarSkin`)

```
<s:ButtonBar id="tabs" y="15" left="0" height="31"
             skinClass="CustomButtonBarSkin"    
             change="VideosMenuBar_changeHandler(event)" requireSelection="true">  
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout gap="1" columnWidth="180" variableColumnWidth="false"   
                            />
    </s:layout>

    <s:ArrayCollection>
        <fx:String>Latest Videos</fx:String>
        <fx:String>Last Week Videos</fx:String>
        <fx:String>Last Month Videos</fx:String>
    </s:ArrayCollection>

</s:ButtonBar>
```

In the skin class look for the part where the buttons are defined as components, and change the `skinClass` attribute of the `ButtonBarButton`'s to a custom skin class (e.g. `CustomButtonBarButtonSkin`).

```
<fx:Component id="firstButton">
    <!-- <s:ButtonBarButton skinClass="spark.skins.spark.ButtonBarFirstButtonSkin" /> -->
    <s:ButtonBarButton skinClass="CustomButtonBarButtonSkin" />
</fx:Component> 
[...]
```

The custom `ButtonBar` skin class is based on `spark.skins.spark.ButtonBarFirstButtonSkin`, `spark.skins.spark.ButtonBarMiddleButtonSkin` or `spark.skins.spark.ButtonBarLastButtonSkin`.

In the custom `ButtonBarButton` skin class, you can add components as you wish. In the case of an image to he left, the class would look something like this.

```
<!-- layer 8: text -->
<!---  @copy spark.components.supportClasses.ButtonBase#labelDisplay -->
<s:Image source="@Embed('bricks.png')" />
<s:Label id="labelDisplay"
         textAlign="center"
         verticalAlign="middle"
         maxDisplayedLines="1"
         horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="1"
         left="10" right="10" top="2" bottom="2">
</s:Label>!
```

[And this it how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGjRk.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but i have a few questions if you could help me..1) i have applied a theme in my app which has made the buttons look somehow without an icon and i would like on top of that put an icon will there be any problem if i apply a skin at the buttonbar despite it has taken some features from the theme? and 2) how can i change the height of each button, i have put height="31" in buttonbar but it changes only the space for the buttonbar without expanding the buttons..any idea? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Another question..3) Can i use an array of objects on order to embed the icon in each one as a dataprovider of the buttonbar or it is a technique regarding mx components?

Comment: 1) Really can't say. You may have to take a closer look at the theme skin files and apply your changes there.

Comment: 2) You can set the button height in the `ButtonBarButton` skin file: `<s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" width="69" height="[height]">`

3) Dou you mean like [this](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/07/28/displaying-icons-in-a-spark-buttonbar-control-in-flex-4/)?

Comment: What i did is to put the property verticalAlign="justify" in the `<s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout gap="1" columnWidth="180" variableColumnWidth="false"   
                            />
    </s:layout>` for the 1) question if you apply a skin over a theme the skin is stronger so the properties of the theme disappear!